# Angular display Django Rest Framework json

Tags: angular

I am very new to AngularJS so please excuse the simplicity of this question.

I am working with the Django Rest Framework and trying to pull back details and display them via Angular JS.  I am copying another project and just trying to extend it a little in order to learn.  I have the following files:

**bar-details.ts**

```
export interface BarDetails {
    id?: number;
    name: string;
    address: string;
    description?: string;
    type?: string;
    openingTime?: number;
    closingTime?: number;
  }
```

**bar-details.provider.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { BarDetails } from './bar-details';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { environment } from '../../environments/environment';

@Injectable()
export class BarDetailsProvider {

  constructor(private http: Http) { }

  getBarDetails(): Observable<BarDetails[]> {
    return this.http.get(`${environment.baseUrl}/bar/1`).map(response => response.json().results as BarDetails[]);
  }
}
```

**bar-details.components.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { BarDetails } from './bar-details';
import { BarDetailsProvider } from './bar-details.provider';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-bar-details',
  templateUrl: './bar-details.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./bar-details.component.scss']
})
export class BarDetailsComponent implements OnInit {

  barDetails: BarDetails[] = [];

  constructor(private barDetailsProvider: BarDetailsProvider) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.barDetailsProvider.getBarDetails().subscribe(barDetails => this.barDetails = barDetails);
  }

}
```

**bar-details.component.html**

```
<div *ngIf="barDetails">
  <h1>{{barDetails.name}}</h1>
  <div>Address: {{barDetails.address}}</div>
</div>
```

My query (which is always returning pk=1 for now) returns this: `{"pk":1,"name":"Carpe Diem","description":"Moderno local con mobiliario minimalista, mesas altas y sofás.","address":"Calle Dr. Fleming, 11","type":"Pub","openingTime":9,"closingTime":24}`

My browser shows a blank page.  This is the HTML generated.

```
<app-bar-details _nghost-c1=""><!--bindings={}-->
</app-bar-details>
```

Where I thought it would show the bar name and address.  What am I getting wrong?

Comment: can you shwo what `response.json()` prints ?

Comment: You're probably returning an array of objects?  You declared barDetails as an array, so I'm assuming that you're not actually returning a single object.  If so, you'll need to use ngFor to display the results.  Also, you might want to look at the [async pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe), so you don't have to expressly subscribe to your observable.

Comment: How do I show `response.json()` ?

Comment: I tried `*NgFor` and that didn't work either.  I'm reading about async pipe now.

Comment: Are there any errors in your console

Comment: No errors in the console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's where I went wrong:

```
@Injectable()
export class BarDetailsProvider {

  constructor(private http: Http) { }

  getBarDetails(): Observable<BarDetails[]> {
    return this.http.get(`${environment.baseUrl}/bar/1`).map(response => response.json().results as BarDetails[]);
  }
}
```

should be

```
@Injectable()
export class BarDetailsProvider {

  constructor(private http: Http) { }

  getBarDetails(): Observable<BarDetails> {
    return this.http.get(`${environment.baseUrl}/bar/1`).map(response => response.json() as BarDetails);
  }
}
```

with `barDetails` not being an array following through to the other files.